# Server side rendering components with children

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, react-router

I have this on my app.tsx (entry point):

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from "react-router";

import layout from "./shared/layout.tsx";
import home from "./home.tsx";
import about from "./about.tsx";
import repos from "./repos.tsx";

render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={layout}>
            <IndexRoute component={home} />
            <Route path="/repos" component={repos} />
            <Route path="/about" component={about} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Everything works great, but now I'm trying to implement server side rendering and I can't render the url `"/"` which is `home.tsx`.

I don't know how to render `layout.tsx` and specify `home.tsx` as the children.

This is `layout.tsx`:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Navlink from "./navlink.tsx";

export default React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        children: React.PropTypes.element.isRequired
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Ghettohub Issues</h1>
                <ul role="nav">
                    <li><Navlink to="/" onlyActiveOnIndex={true}>Home</Navlink></li>
                    <li><Navlink to="/about">About</Navlink></li>
                    <li><Navlink to="/repos">Repos</Navlink></li>
                </ul>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

And this is what I'm doing on the server side (`index.cshtml`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="/assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    @Html.React("Components.layout", new { }, containerId: "app")
    <script src="~/assets/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So how do I specify that I want `home.tsx` to be the `children` of `layout.tsx`?

Comment: React router server side requires using the `match` command to generate the route and then return `renderToString`. https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md

Comment: ok, but how to do that with reactjs.net?